# Counting TRUE's in measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I've got this piece of code that checks which machines we made are currently active. The current standard for an active machine is that it produced 25 widgets per week at least, for the the last four weeks straight. Writing this in DAX wasn't that hard, but we're not happy with the definition. Current problem is that if the workes for one machine take a week off the machine now counts as inactive, even though its just one week < 25 widgets. What we now want to do is change the definition to 3/4 weeks for the past four weeks. This way a machine isnt marked inactive over one slow week.

This turned out to be harder than I thought. My initial idea was just making a VAR counter = 0 and just counting each TRUE for each week, if the counter is 3 or above the machine is active. Problem is I just cannot figure out how to use VARs in DAX, I just dont get it.

```
ActiveMachines = IF( 
    (CALCULATE(SUM('Query1'[TrayProduced Hourly]),
              DATESINPERIOD('Query1'[TrayProducedDay].[Date]
                            ,CALCULATE(MAX('Query1'[TrayProducedDay].[Date]), FILTER(ALL('Query1'), 'Query1'[TrayProduced Hourly]))
                            ,-7
                            ,DAY)
             ) > 25 &&  
    CALCULATE(SUM('Query1'[TrayProduced Hourly]),
              DATESINPERIOD('Query1'[TrayProducedDay].[Date]
                            ,(CALCULATE(MAX('Query1'[TrayProducedDay].[Date]), FILTER(ALL('Query1'), 'Query1'[TrayProduced Hourly])) - 7)
                            ,-7
                            ,DAY)
             ) > 25 && 
    CALCULATE(SUM('Query1'[TrayProduced Hourly]),
              DATESINPERIOD('Query1'[TrayProducedDay].[Date]
                            ,(CALCULATE(MAX('Query1'[TrayProducedDay].[Date]), FILTER(ALL('Query1'), 'Query1'[TrayProduced Hourly])) - 14)
                            ,-7
                            ,DAY)
             ) > 25 && 
    CALCULATE(SUM('Query1'[TrayProduced Hourly]),
              DATESINPERIOD('Query1'[TrayProducedDay].[Date]
                            ,(CALCULATE(MAX('Query1'[TrayProducedDay].[Date]), FILTER(ALL('Query1'), 'Query1'[TrayProduced Hourly])) - 21)
                            ,-7
                            ,DAY)
             ) > 25), TRUE, FALSE)
```

The code above currently works, now what would I need to add to this (or remove, or whatever else) to get my idea to work here? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on the PowerBi forums too, there I got this answer that worked out for me:

```
ActiveMachines = IF( 
(IF(CALCULATE(SUM('MetricsQuery'[TrayProduced Hourly]),
          DATESINPERIOD('MetricsQuery'[TrayProducedDate].[Date]
                        ,CALCULATE(MAX('MetricsQuery'[TrayProducedDate].[Date]), FILTER('MetricsQuery', 'MetricsQuery'[TrayProduced Hourly]))
                        ,-7
                        ,DAY)
        ), 1) +  
IF(CALCULATE(SUM('MetricsQuery'[TrayProduced Hourly]),
          DATESINPERIOD('MetricsQuery'[TrayProducedDate].[Date]
                        ,(CALCULATE(MAX('MetricsQuery'[TrayProducedDate].[Date]), FILTER('MetricsQuery', 'MetricsQuery'[TrayProduced Hourly])) - 7)
                        ,-7
                        ,DAY)
        ), 1) + 
IF(CALCULATE(SUM('MetricsQuery'[TrayProduced Hourly]),
          DATESINPERIOD('MetricsQuery'[TrayProducedDate].[Date]
                        ,(CALCULATE(MAX('MetricsQuery'[TrayProducedDate].[Date]), FILTER('MetricsQuery', 'MetricsQuery'[TrayProduced Hourly])) - 14)
                        ,-7
                        ,DAY)
         ), 1) + 
IF(CALCULATE(SUM('MetricsQuery'[TrayProduced Hourly]),
          DATESINPERIOD('MetricsQuery'[TrayProducedDate].[Date]
                        ,(CALCULATE(MAX('MetricsQuery'[TrayProducedDate].[Date]), FILTER('MetricsQuery', 'MetricsQuery'[TrayProduced Hourly])) - 21)
                        ,-7
                        ,DAY)
        ), 1) 
          >= 3), TRUE, FALSE)
```